# Closure question from Enderton's 'Elements of Set-theory'

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on the following question but am unsure how to prove that $C^{*} \subseteq C_{*}$. Any help and comments would be appreciated. For those with Enderton's text on-hand, the page number is 78 and the question is #9.

---

Let $f$ be a function from $B$ into $B$, and assume that $A \subseteq B$. Define $C^{*} = \cap \{X \ | \ A \subseteq X \subseteq B \ \& \ f[X] \subseteq X\}$. Further, define the function $h$ where $h(0) = A, h(n^{+}) = h(n) \cup f[h(n)]$. We also define $C_{*} = \cup_{i \in \omega} h(i)$. We prove that $C^{*} = C_{*}$.

---

We first show that $C_{*} \subseteq C^{*}$. Let $x \in C_{*}$. We show that $\forall n \in \omega$, $h(n) \subseteq C^{*}$. Let $ x \in h(0)$. Then $x \in A$, since $h(0) = A \ \& \ A \subseteq C^{*}$, $x \in C^{*}$. Let $x \in h(k) \ \implies \ x \in C^{*}$. We assume that $x \in h(k^{+})$ to show that $x \in C^{*}$. By the definition of $h(k^{+})$, we have $x \in h(k) \cup f[h(k)]$. Case #1: $x \in h(k) \implies x \in C^{*}$ by our inductive assumption. Case #2: Say $x \in f[h(k)]$. Since $h(k) \subseteq C^{*}$, we have $f[h(k)] \subseteq h(k) \subseteq C^{*}$. So $x \in C^{*}$ and we have shown that $C_{*} \subseteq C^{*}$ by induction.

We next show that $C^{*} \subseteq C_{*}$ by showing that $f[C_{*}] \subseteq C_{*}$. Let $x \in C^{*}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. If you show that $f[C_*]\subseteq C_*$ then you in fact show that $C_*$ is in the collection over which we take an intersection to define $C^*$ in which case it has to be that $C^*\subseteq C_*$, and from what you have shown before it means that equality ensues.

To show that $f[C_*]\subseteq C_*$ simply note that if $x\in C_*$ then for some $n\in\omega$ we have that $x\in h(n)$. What does that tell you about $f(x)$?

Comment: Thank you Asaf for your helpful comment.

Comment: You're welcome.